# What are the common scenarios for Circular Dependencies in Spring and how to resolve them?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, circular-dependency

I want to know-

1. When can we get Circular Dependency?
2. How to avoid Circular Dependency?
3. How does Spring handles Circular Dependency?

Below code is just a dummy to understand circular dependency but did not get Circular Dependency issue.

```
@Component
public class ParentClass {
    @Autowired
    ChildClass childClassObject;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    protected int i = 0;

    public void parentMethod(){
        System.out.println("Parent Method");
        ChildClass c = (ChildClass) context.getBean("childClass");
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

@Component
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{

    @Autowired
    ParentClass parentClassObject;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    public void childMethod(){
        System.out.println("Child Class");
        ParentClass parent = (ParentClass) context.getBean("parentClass");
        parent.i++;
        System.out.println(parent.i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You _did_ get a circular dependency, spring was just able to resolve it (through lazy autowiring) since you `@Autowired` on the field.  If you try constructor injection: `public ChildClass(final ParentClass parent) {...` and `public ParentClass(final ChildClass child) {...` I suspect you'll see the issue.

Comment: Yes, in a constructor  we can get circular dependency and can be resolved by using @Lazy annotation. Such as 
`@Autowired
public ParentClass(@Lazy ChildClass c){........
}`

Comment: Does it mean, circular dependency can only happen in Constructor injection not in Setter Injection or in any other ways?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

1- You can get a circular dependency when in a hierarchy of bean you found link in two directions, for example let's say you have three beans BeanA, BeanB and BeanC; you have a circular dependency if BeanA need BeanB, and BeanB need BeanC, and BeanC need BeanA.

2- You can avoid it by identify links between your bean, some tools can provide you the dependency hierarchy for huge application. But if the lins is mandatory, you can use setter to deal with dependency. Instead of constructor and @Autowired method, use setter

3- Spring can't handle it. since we need to know which bean to create before the other. Remember in bean creation spring will create all dependent beans before creating the target , so if to create BeanA you need BeanB, and to create BeanB you need BeanA, spring will not know which one to create first.

Comment: Here in my code I tries A -> B and B -> A where -> is dependency.
I think (correct if I am wrong) spring takes care of it as the beans are instantiated first, then injected into each other !?

Comment: to achieve what you are looking for you can use either:
* setters
* Lazy annotation on @Autowired.
Warning this will lead you to more work when it comes to unit tests your code (since you can't use constructor injection anymore)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, that is how you get a circular dependency.  Obviously the chains can be longer and more convoluted.  A -> B, B -> C, C -> A, etc.
2. There's no 'one way' to avoid them.  You could factor out the *parts* of the dependencies which need to know about each other (for example, if `A` only needs one method from `B`, pull that method out to another class and have *both* `A` and `B` depend on that instead).  You can add some mediating class (`ABManager`) which has a dependency on *both* `A` and `B`, and handles managing the interactions between the two (without the two of them needing to depend directly on each other).
3. It depends on how you ask it to handle it.  If you have constructor injection directly, it can't.  If you are doing field injection it can instantiate the beans first, and then handle all the autowiring (at which point both are already available).  As you mention in your comment, `@Lazy` is also there for handling things through placeholder proxies to be filled in later.